# Why does PHP treat << (double less than) as a tag in strip_tags?

Tags: php

I have a problem that PHP treats `<<` as a tag when using `strip_tags`. I have some text where I am stripping the formatting and then I save the content to a file. If I only have one `<` then it does not strip it.

The reason for me to use `strip_tags` is that I show a webpage with some HTML formatting (colors) and then I want the same output as the user can see on the webpage to a file - but without the HTML tags for colors etc.

The purpose here is to strip all known/valid HTML tags from my text and leave the rest as-is. This is not a security thing to prevent malicious code to show on webpage.

My PHP code is:

```
$txt = "this is << line 2 > but it does not work";
$fline = strip_tags($txt);
$fh = fopen("file.txt","w");
fwrite($fh,$fline);
fclose($fh);
```

If I have this input, with only one `<` then the output in the file will be the exact same as the input text and this is also as expected:

```
this is < line 1 > and it works
```

But when I have this input text:

```
this is << line 2 > but it does not work
```

.. then the output in my file will strip both the `<<` and the content within the fictive tag:

```
this is  but it does not work
```

Why does PHP treat `<<` as a tag (but not `<`) and how can I allow the `<<` since it does not work to do this:

```
$fline = strip_tags($txt,"<<");
```

You will most likely reply "*but why do you use strip_tags in the first place*" - I do that because it has worked for me until now ;-) I may need to rewrite the logic behind it, if this is impossible to fix but at least I then have an explanation why `<<` is treated as a tag where `<` is not.

Comment: FWIW, `strip_tags` is a pretty crude tool for a problem you should avoid having in the first place; I'd suggest you try your luck with a more sophisticated tool: http://htmlpurifier.org.

Comment: To the person who has down-voted this and suggested for closure of this ticket then it would be great with some explanation for these actions? I feel the question is pretty well defined and scoped nor are there any duplicates as far as I can see?

Comment: I do not know, how it exactly works, but You can examine the algorithm here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L5010

Comment: @deceze - I have read the description for "HTML Purifier" and as far as I can see it cannot strip HTML formatting? This is what I want to achieve here. I want to have all standard HTML tags removed but it should leave the non-HTML stuff as-is.

Comment: By default HTMLPurifier strips *certain* tags and attributes (only allows certain things and strips everything else); if you tweak its whitelist to basically zero, it should strip everything.

Comment: @deceze - yes and this is NOT what I want here. I want to keep my own tags... e.g. `<<` or `< blaaaa >` should be left as-is. With HTMLPurifier it seems I need to define a whitelist and that's not possible for me to do as I can invent new tags tomorrow.

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing the `<<` and `>>` with HTML entities, then `strip_tags()` will omit them, but the browser will display them as `<<` and `>>`

Comment: This is not what I want as it then in the output file would show as `&lt;&lt;`.